# How to avoid submiting the form without selecting value in combo box c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project, create view consist of a main view and another couple of partial views.

So in one partial view, there is a combo box, I want to restrict it without selecting a value, so the user cannot submit the form.

I tried writing a javascript within that partial view, but it won't work. So want to know is there are any other ways to do this restriction?

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     @Html.Label("Select the Approver", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-sm-8">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Approver_Id, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @id = "ddlEmployees", @class = "js-dropdown" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Approver_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

I cant use it on the `model` as `required` because some options in this combo box get hidden before submitting the form. So If I apply `required` to the model, the form does not get submitted for those options also.

Any suggestions would help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to handle this server-side you can do it client-side by JS.

> $('#submitDemo').click(
> if(!$("drpval").val()>0)
> return false;
> );